# How to fix python encoding error - u'g\xe3\xbcnstig' to u'g\xfcnstig'

Tags: python, python-2.7

Spent hours to figure out a certain problem. And now I am stuck with getting it fixed because of an encoding issue. I have no idea what is happening here. Can an1 help?

I have string `"günstig"` and my unicode string contains the following

```
u'g\xe3\xbcnstig'
```

which prints to `gã¼nstig`

what do I need to do is, to turn it into

```
u'g\xfcnstig'
```

so it prints

```
günstig
```

What's the best recipe for that?

Thanks so much.

**info update**

the string comes from a very garbled json datasource. 
this is how I decode it to a unicode object

`concatHTML.decode('string_escape').replace("\\","").decode('utf-8'`)

Comment: how did you get your unicode string? use utf8 decoding instead of latin1

Comment: I get the string from a very garbled json datasource. I decode the string with utf-8.. see the update in my post.

Comment: nope. thats exactly it...

Comment: Could you show the output of `print repr(concatHTML)`?

Comment: Probably you shouldn't do `.decode('string_escape').replace("\\","")` - so show `concatHTML` first.

Comment: While working with encoding problems, first try to determine the encoding of the source. You did not help us by not giving us the source, but clearly here, for me, using .decode('string_escape').replace("\\","") seems a wrong start.